# Return error when returning a reference

Tags: c++, error-handling, reference

A function returns a reference on int

```
int&     MyClass::getElement(int position)
{
   if (position < _size)
      return (_array[position]);
   return ([...]) // An Error
}
```

My first think was to return NULL.
But obviously a reference can not be NULL.

What is the right way to return an error in this case?

Comment: The only way that does not involve a magic number is raising an exception.

Comment: I agree with the current answers but I want to add a point: an exception is for when your function cannot stick to its own interface. In this case, the interface promises that "if you give me an `int`, I will give you another `int` back". Since the error case breaks this contract, it's an exceptional situation.

Comment: You should also check for a negative index, or use an unsigned type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various options, roughly ordered with my preferred options first:

- Throw an exception, conventionally `std::out_of_range`
- Return a pointer
- Return some other type with a well-define invalid value, like `std::pair<bool,int&>` or `boost::optional<int&>`. This is more useful if you want to return something by value, not reference, so can't return a pointer.
- Return a reference to a static magic number, if you can choose a number which will never be valid data. This is nasty since there's nothing to stop the caller from modifying it.

Answer (score 3):

The right way is to throw an exception of type `std::out_of_range` in case parameter position has no acceptable value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return reference, you have to throw an exception in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to think about is that, even if you were returning an 'int' (i.e. not a reference), NULL would be 0 (and so easily confused with a valid int value that is '0').

If you want to stick to this function definition, then throw an exception to signal an error.

```
int&     MyClass::getElement(int position)
{
   if (position < _size)
      return (_array[position]);

   throw std::out_of_range("Invalid size to getElement");
}
```

Comment: `range_error` would be more conventional than `invalid_argument`.

Comment: (By which I meant `out_of_range`, sorry).